# #define was changed to constexpr auto

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I defined some code in c++, ex:

```
#define array_width 3;
```

Visual Studio will suggest changing to:

```
constexpr auto array_width = 3;
```

what's the reason to change? and what is the benefit?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `#define array_width 3`, but you will not get an error on that line, no. You'll get a sea of syntactic errors for each use. Now that is one reason to use the second.

Comment: The `=` sign will not usually be in the macro.

Comment: @LogicStuff - SNAP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for these suggestions is that the preprocessor does nothing but simple textual replacement (no type checking or similar things a compiler performs). There are many potential pitfalls when using the preprocessor - when you can avoid it, do so. `constexpr´ is one of the building blocks that allow for fewer macros these days.

To back this with an authority: From S. Meyers, Effective C++, Item 2 ("Prefer `const`s, `enum`s, and `inline`s to `#define`s"):

> **Things to Remember**
>
> - For simple constants, prefer `const` objects or `enum`s to `#define`s
> - [...]

From S. Meyers, Effective Modern C++, Item 15 ("Use `constexpr` whenever possible"):

> **Things to Remember**
>
> - `constexpr` objects are `const` and are initialized with values known during
>     compilation.
> - [...]
> - `constexpr` objects and functions may be used in a wider range of contexts than non-`constexpr` objects and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Macros work by substituting text. With macro the following example code will be ill-formed:

```
struct foo
{
    int array_width{};
};
```

So in modern C++ one should prefer to avoid macros when there are alternatives available. Also it is a good idea to use `UNIQUE_PREFIX_UPPER_CASE` naming convention for macros to avoid possible clashes with normal code.